# Open jboss-6.1.0.Final to all interface

Tags: jboss

How to open jboss-6.1.0.Final to all interfaces so I can connect remotely?

Answer (score 2):

If you mean the AS6, than you need to start the application server with the following option:

```
-b, --host=<host or ip>       Bind address for all JBoss services


./JBOSS_HOME/bin/run.sh –b 0.0.0.0
```

Comment: +1 for giving this valuable information

Answer (score 0):

Are you working on Windows oder Linux?

Windows:

$JBOSS_HOME/bin/domain.bat

Linux:

$JBOSS_HOME/bin/domain.sh

Comment: I am on Windows. Where is located domain.bat?

Comment: in which directory(JBOSS_HOME) did you unpack the .rar or .zip file that you download?

Comment: In C:/ , but i think that i don't have domain.bat file.

Comment: Tell what do you have in the bin directory?